# My list (f3) is not printing an output and keeps giving me StaleElementReferenceException?

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I've been working on this part of the code for the past week and I've managed to get a better understanding of the codelogic. To let you know: I'm trying to scrape founder info (name, gender, school info) for every electric vehicle company on crunchbase. I've figured the way I should do it is by creating different dictionaries as some of the info is on different parts of the page. Here's the code below:

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
import time

#driver path
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#access crunchbase ui
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)
    
time.sleep(3)
   
#await element location

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('//a[@aria-label="Next"][@aria-disabled="false"][@type="button"]'))))
    
#next page
page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[1]/div/results-info/h3/a[2]')

company_list = [] ###create dictionary
   
counter = 0
for _ in range(2):
    if counter == 1:
        break
    counter += 1
    
    if page.is_displayed():
        
        time.sleep(25)
        
        #webscrape through iterations/rows
        all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("grid-row")
                                                      
        for row in all_rows:
            companyname = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="identifier-label"]')
            companyname.click()
            time.sleep(10)
            
            ###founder info
            founders = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > chrome > div > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav-content > div > ng-component > entity-v2 > page-layout > div > div > div > page-centered-layout:nth-child(3) > div > div > div.main-content > row-card:nth-child(2) > profile-section > section-card > mat-card > div.section-content-wrapper > div > fields-card:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(4) > field-formatter > identifier-multi-formatter > span > a")
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(founders).perform()
            founders.click()
            f1 = {
                'founder name': driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="profile-name"]').text.strip(),
                'founder gender': driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > chrome > div > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav-content > div > ng-component > entity-v2 > page-layout > div > div > div > page-centered-layout.ng-star-inserted > div > div > div.main-content > row-card:nth-child(1) > profile-section > section-card > mat-card > div.section-content-wrapper > div > fields-card:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(3) > field-formatter > span').text.strip(),
                }
            fschool = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > chrome > div > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav-content > div > ng-component > entity-v2 > page-layout > div > div > div > page-centered-layout.ng-star-inserted > div > div > div.main-content > row-card:nth-child(7) > profile-section > section-card > mat-card > div.section-content-wrapper > div > image-list-card > ul > li > div > field-formatter:nth-child(5) > span')
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(fschool).perform()
            f2 = {
                'school': driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > chrome > div > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav-content > div > ng-component > entity-v2 > page-layout > div > div > div > page-centered-layout.ng-star-inserted > div > div > div.main-content > row-card:nth-child(7) > profile-section > section-card > mat-card > div.section-content-wrapper > div > image-list-card > ul > li > div > a').text.strip(),
                'degree type': driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > chrome > div > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav-content > div > ng-component > entity-v2 > page-layout > div > div > div > page-centered-layout.ng-star-inserted > div > div > div.main-content > row-card:nth-child(7) > profile-section > section-card > mat-card > div.section-content-wrapper > div > image-list-card > ul > li > div > field-formatter:nth-child(2) > span').text.strip(),
                'degree': driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > chrome > div > mat-sidenav-container > mat-sidenav-content > div > ng-component > entity-v2 > page-layout > div > div > div > page-centered-layout.ng-star-inserted > div > div > div.main-content > row-card:nth-child(7) > profile-section > section-card > mat-card > div.section-content-wrapper > div > image-list-card > ul > li > div > field-formatter:nth-child(3) > span').text.strip()
                }
            f3 = {**f1, **f2}
            print(f3)
            company_list.append(f1)
        print("next")
        page.click()
    
    
#create dataframe    
df = pd.DataFrame(company_list)

print(df)

#create excel writer object
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('crunchbasedemo.xlsx')

#export to excel
df.to_excel(writer)

writer.save()



print("It's alive!")
```

For some reason f3 (the merged f1 & f2 dictionaries) won't print and I keep receiving this error when I get to the print point:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Any ideas ?

Edited Code:

```
hrefs=[x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="component--field-formatter field-type-identifier link-accent ng-star-inserted"]')]
names=[x.get_attribute('title') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="component--field-formatter field-type-identifier link-accent ng-star-inserted"]')]
print(names)
print(hrefs)

company_list=[]

for href in hrefs:    
    driver.get(href)
    try: 
        founders=[x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='ng-star-inserted' and contains(.,'Founders')]//a[@class='link-accent ng-star-inserted']")]
        founder_names = [x.get_attribute('title') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='ng-star-inserted' and contains(.,'Founders')]//a[@class='link-accent ng-star-inserted']")]
        print(founder_names)
        for founder in founders:
            driver.get(founder)
            try:
                fschool = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//li[@class='ng-star-inserted']//a[@class='link-accent'])[5]")
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(fschool).perform() 
                print(fschool)
            except:
                pass
    except: 
        pass
```

Comment: Where is _f3 (the merged f1 & f2 dictionaries)_? dictionary should have been `company_list = {}`

Comment: @DebanjanB scroll down in the code

Comment: each click is probably going to have some effect on the DOM.  That will make your "all_rows" references stale.

Comment: any suggestions ? @pcalkins

Comment: I suggest grabbing the hrefs and then driver.get to those hrefs.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan hrefs for every single company ?

Comment: If you look //*[@class="identifier-label"]  is actually surrounded by an a tag which hold s the hrefs for each of those companies. You can construct a list by doing [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="component--field-formatter field-type-identifier link-accent ng-star-inserted"] ')] would get the entire pages companies hrefs to transpose which also solves staleelements  by looping those.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan would the founders info block of code need to be changed ?

Comment: @truee Here's a demo on how to grab hrefs and just simply go to their pages which prevents StaleElements. This can be extended for any other clicks that you need to do with a tags. Also your founders code needs to change to account for multiple founders and etc.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is not complete**

```
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.title)

hrefs=[x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="component--field-formatter field-type-identifier link-accent ng-star-inserted"]')]
names=[x.get_attribute('title') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="component--field-formatter field-type-identifier link-accent ng-star-inserted"]')]
print(names)
print(hrefs)
company_list=[]
for href in hrefs:    
    driver.get(href)
    try: 
        founders=[x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='ng-star-inserted' and contains(.,'Founders')]//a[@class='link-accent ng-star-inserted']")]
        founder_names = [x.get_attribute('title') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='ng-star-inserted' and contains(.,'Founders')]//a[@class='link-accent ng-star-inserted']")]
        print(founder_names)
        for founder in founders:
            driver.get(founder)
    except:
        pass
```

Outputs:

```
Query Builder | Organizations | Crunchbase
['Bird', 'Rivian', 'Zoomo', 'NIO', 'Tesla', 'Ample', 'Rad Power Bikes', 'Wallbox', 'ChargePoint', 'Ather Energy', 'SES', 'Ola Electric', 'EVgo', 'Canoo', 'Wayve']
['https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/bird', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/rivian-automotive', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/bolt-bikes', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/nextev', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/tesla-motors', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ample-6b70', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/rad-power-bikes', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/wallbox', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/chargepoint', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ather-energy', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/solidenergy', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ola-electric', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/nrg-evgo', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/canoo-tech', 'https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/wayve-9739']
['Travis VanderZanden']
['Robert J. Scaringe']
['Jack Cheng', 'Lihong Qin', 'William Li']
['Elon Musk', 'JB Straubel', 'Marc Tarpenning', 'Martin Eberhard']
['Mike Radenbaugh', 'Tyler Collins']
['Eduard Castañeda Mañé', 'Enric Asunción']
['Arun Vinayak', 'Swapnil Jain', 'Tarun Mehta']
[]
['Andrew Wolstan', 'Richard Kim', 'Stefan Krause', 'Ulrich Kranz']
```

So to currently go to each href just collect the hrefs using .get_attribute('href')  and then driver.get(href) to them. This prevents StaleElementExceptions which arise from moving from the page to loop through elements. This goes by checking each company if they have a founder section and if they have multiples then proceeds to go to each of their pages.

Comment: so how would I go about retrieving each founders school as well ?

Comment: You could actually reuse your code since all this does is go to each founder for each company. Just wrap it in a try except so you can set each value to none in case it's not on the page.

Comment: the edited code (added above) isn't returning the school information for some reason and the dataframe also seems to be failing...any idea?

Comment: Use a try except in case you miss elements and set them to none.

Comment: Not all pages will have  the same css selector and so forth.

Comment: okay so should I refer to hrefs again ? and should I set the try except    inside "for founder in founders:" ?

Comment: I would put it inside for founder.

Comment: check out the edited code - the bot keeps skipping the new try statement. why is that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239463/discussion-between-truee-and-arundeep-chohan).

Comment: If the css selector doesn't find elements then it'll skip make sure the selector you use are correct.